# Não foi possível localizar o arquivo 'c:\ ... \bin\roslyn\csc.exe'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Segue imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fui atualizar **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** com a versão mais recente e estável. Então atualizei 1.0.5 para 1.0.6.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele não estava mais assim. Agora fica dando esse problema.

Comment: Mudei .Net Framework de 4.5.2 para 4.7 e problema não aparece mais. Não estou confiante nisso ai.

Comment: Aconteceu a mesma coisa comigo.
Removi esse pacote e tudo esta funcionando.
Se alguma coisa parar eu volto aqui e te conto!
Abraço. Barini